# How to find the index of the last maximum in julialang?

Tags: julia

I have an array that contains repeated nonnegative integers, e.g., `A=[5,5,5,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,3,0,0]`. I would like to find the position of the last maximum in `A`. That is the largest index `i` such that `A[i]>=A[j]` for all `j`. In my example, `i=3`.

I tried to find the indices of all maximum of `A` then find the maximum of these indices:

```
A = [5,5,5,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,3,0,0];
Amax = maximum(A);
i = maximum(find(x -> x == Amax, A));
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: If you want a fast solution probably you should write a custom function exactly like `findmax` in Base, but replace `if ai > m` with `if ai >= m`. Using standard functions you can write `length(A)+1-indmax(reverse(A))`, the drawback is that it performs a copy of `A`.

Comment: Alex Arslan just told me on Slack that 0.7 has an `Iterators.reverse` function that creates a view.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Iterators.reverse doesn't support indmax. (`ERROR: MethodError: no method matching keys(::Base.Iterators.Reverse{String})`. Slack is public?

Comment: ah, right. Yes it is, but you need an invite. I think if you go to slackinvite.julialang.org you can request one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
length(A) - indmax(@view A[end:-1:1]) + 1
```

should be pretty fast, but I didn't benchmark it.

EDIT: I should note that by definition @crstnbr 's solution (to write the algorithm from scratch) is faster (how much faster is shown in Xiaodai's response). This is an attempt to do it using julia's inbuilt array functions.

Answer (score 4):

What about `findlast(A.==maximum(A))` (which of course is conceptually similar to your approach)?

The fastest thing would probably be explicit loop implementation like this:

```
function lastindmax(x)
   k = 1
   m = x[1]
   @inbounds for i in eachindex(x)
       if x[i]>=m
           k = i
           m = x[i]
       end
   end
   return k
end
```

Comment: At least in 0.6 it is faster to keep and update a `maxval` value, rather than do two index lookups for each iteration. Putting on a `@inbounds` also seems to help.

Comment: @DNF yes, you're right. Not that it really matters here but I adjusted the post.

Comment: I just mentioned it because you talked about the fastest way. Those changes cut almost 40% off the runtime for me.

Answer (score 3):

Michael's solution doesn't support Strings (`ERROR: MethodError: no method matching view(::String, ::StepRange{Int64,Int64})`) or sequences so I add another solution:

```
julia> lastimax(x) = maximum((j,i) for (i,j) in enumerate(x))[2]
julia> A="abžcdž"; lastimax(A)  # unicode is OK
6
julia> lastimax(i^2 for i in -10:7)
1
```

If you more like don't catch exception for empty Sequence:

```
julia> lastimax(x) = !isempty(x) ? maximum((j,i) for (i,j) in enumerate(x))[2] : 0;
julia> lastimax(i for i in 1:3 if i>4)
0
```

**Simple(!)** benchmarks:

This is up to **10 times slower** than Michael's solution for **Float64**:

```
julia> mlastimax(A) = length(A) - indmax(@view A[end:-1:1]) + 1;
julia> julia> A = rand(Float64, 1_000_000); @time lastimax(A); @time mlastimax(A)
  0.166389 seconds (4.00 M allocations: 91.553 MiB, 4.63% gc time)
  0.019560 seconds (6 allocations: 240 bytes)
80346
```

(I am surprised) it is **2 times faster** for **Int64**!

```
julia> A = rand(Int64, 1_000_000); @time lastimax(A); @time mlastimax(A)
  0.015453 seconds (10 allocations: 304 bytes)
  0.031197 seconds (6 allocations: 240 bytes)
423400
```

it is **2-3 times slower** for **Strings**

```
julia> A = ["A$i" for i in 1:1_000_000]; @time lastimax(A); @time   mlastimax(A)
  0.175117 seconds (2.00 M allocations: 61.035 MiB, 41.29% gc time)
  0.077098 seconds (7 allocations: 272 bytes)
999999
```

EDIT2: 
@crstnbr solution is faster and works with Strings too (doesn't work with generators). There difference between `lastindmax` and `lastimax` - first return byte index, second return character index:

```
julia> S = "1š3456789ž"
julia> length(S)
10
julia> lastindmax(S)  # return value is bigger than length
11
julia> lastimax(S)  # return character index (which is not byte index to String) of last max character
10

julia> S[chr2ind(S, lastimax(S))]
'ž': Unicode U+017e (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)

julia> S[chr2ind(S, lastimax(S))]==S[lastindmax(S)]
true
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried @Michael's solution and @crstnbr's solution and I found the latter much faster

```
a = rand(Int8(1):Int8(5),1_000_000_000)

@time length(a) - indmax(@view a[end:-1:1]) + 1 # 19 seconds
@time length(a) - indmax(@view a[end:-1:1]) + 1 # 18 seconds


function lastindmax(x)
   k = 1
   m = x[1]
   @inbounds for i in eachindex(x)
       if x[i]>=m
           k = i
           m = x[i]
       end
   end
   return k
end

@time lastindmax(a) # 3 seconds
@time lastindmax(a) # 2.8 seconds
```

Comment: Can you report the timings? :-)

Comment: Right, I did them - they're like 17 to 3 seconds. @crstnbr's solution is probably the most efficient you can program - my solution is just shorthand, it includes an algorithm like that + some more calculations, so it's slower.